# How accesible is Mathematics research?

Tags: mathematics, research-undergraduate

To do Mathematics, one doesn't need much more than actual Mathematics book and perhaps lecture. There is been a growing trend of having open source resource of both book and lecture on the internet in the last twenty years. This leads me to the question, is Mathematics research highly accessible compared to other fields? Or are there some subject related hindrances preventing it being so?

Comment: At least in the US, I would say that at an undergraduate level research is much more common in lab sciences than math.  So depending on what you mean by accessible, and what fields you are comparing to, no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends what you mean "accessible", of course. Accessible as in: you do have access to the material and tools to do it: yeah! Super accessible. You just need paper, a pen, and access to books. Now, the reason why maths research is niche and limited is not because people can't read the books or have the tools, its because its damn hard to get a research-level understanding of math, so very few people have the time and brainpower to learn and understand it. So very not accessible in that sense, and way easier to get into other fields of research.

However, this is talking about high-level research. If you are looking for undergraduate level knowledge, indeed its quite accessible, but nowadays it is true for many other sciences too...

Comment: An anecdote: In Kenya, access to books is difficult. A person in my region asked academics to contribute books (publisher copies mostly - textbooks) and he filled a shipping container and shipped it there (his place of origin) at, I think, his own expense.

Comment: @Buffy fair point! Not trying to imply that getting material is trivial for everyone, but if nowadays there is _something_ that is easy, its the books. There are also ways (legal or not) to get them online, which did not exist before.

Comment: Hmmm. Don't take it as criticism. Take it as encouragement to do the same.

Comment: "Now, the reason why maths research is niche and limited is not because people can't read the books or have the tools, its because its damn hard to get a research-level understanding of math": Well, many people simply find math uninteresting. E.g. I have a keen interest in maths as a non-mathematician, and I have an above-average (among engineers) math knowledge, but along the years I've come to the conclusion that I find large parts of maths uninteresting and I simply wouldn't work on that.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano sure, but I doubt math is so extremely uninteresting for such a bit portion of the population that causes lack of research, so while what you say its true, I don't think there is a relationship between the two concepts.